# Design Optimal Algorithm to find the values of 'a' and 'b'

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numbers

Suppose, we are given a composite number (**n**>3), can be written as:   `n = a*b`, where a and b are any integer numbers.

Now, our task is to calculate the values of **a** & **b**, such that the function `f(a,b) = |a-b|` get minimized.
.

I have implemented the [image] approach, given below:

```cpp
int n;
cin >> n;      //  Take it from the user

/* Now, find the value of the a and b */
int a = 1;
int b = n;
int temp_a;
int temp_b;

for(temp_a=1; temp_a<=sqrt(n); temp_a++) {
    if(n % temp_a == 0) {
        temp_b = n / temp_a;

        if((temp_b - temp_a) < (b - a)) {
            b = temp_b;
            a = temp_a;
        }
    }
}

print a and b
```

But want to reduce it to [image] or better, **if possible**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find maximal divisor of *N* not greater than *sqrt(N)*. The simplest way to do it is to iterate over all the possible divisors and check them. It takes *O(sqrt(N))* time in worst case.

Unfortunately, there is no way to solve this problem in *O(log N)* time in worst case. In fact, it is not possible to do it even in *O((log N)^p)* time for any *p*. It is easy to show that if it were possible, then you would be able to find [prime factorization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorization.html) of any number in polynomial time of its size in bytes. No one can do it right now, and there is a widely used [RSA cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), which strongly relies on the fact that no one can factorize numbers so fast. That is one of the reasons everyone is so scared of [quantum computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Potential) =)

However, there are algorithms asymptotically faster than *O(sqrt(N))*. Also, there are some faster heuristic algorithms for factorization. I strongly advice reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) on the matter.

One of the ways to slightly improve complexity is to precompute all the primes up to *sqrt(N)*. Then if you try to divide *N* only by them, you would be able to find prime factorization of *N*. Knowing the prime factorization, you can efficiently iterate over all the possible divisors with a recursive search. Finding the factorization takes as much time as there are primes being checked, i.e. *O(sqrt(N) / log(N))*. Iterating over all divisors takes time proportional to number of those divisors, which is [asymptotically less than any polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate) of *N*.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time to find an optimal solution for this question but failed. Then I tried to test whether @psyco's approach was better or @Nyavro's. Personally I thought that counting down from `sqrt(n) to 1` must be better but to check @psyco's argument, I implemented both approaches in a python program and plotted a graph to compare the number of iterations both could take to find solution. The graph is for all composite numbers between 4 to 10000. Below is my Python implementation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
X = 10001
n1 = [0]*X
n2 = []
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(X))+1):
    if n1[i] == 0:
        for j in range(i*i, X, i):
            n1[j] = 1

for i in range(4, X):
    if n1[i] == 1:
        n2.append(i)

#print n2
count = []
count2 = []
for n in n2:
    a = 1
    b = n
    c = 0
    flag = 0
    for ta in range(int(math.sqrt(n)), 0, -1):
        c += 1
        if n % ta == 0:
            tb = n / ta
            flag = 1
            if tb-ta <= b-a:
                a = ta
                b = tb
                if flag == 1:
                    break
    count.append(c)
    a = 1
    b = n
    c = 0
    for ta in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        c += 1
        if n % ta == 0:
            tb = n / ta
            if tb-ta <= b-a:
                a = ta
                b = tb

    count2.append(c)

plt.plot(n2, count, 'o')
plt.plot(n2, count2, 'o')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output graph:

[image: Comparison]

The green border above is @psyco's code and the blue ones are @Nyavro's approach. They both can take almost the same time for a lot of inputs though for many cases @Nyavro's approach is better.

Comment: You are right. I know, it can be done in reverse order. But, the critical cases are not covered yet. They still take same time. That's why i asked *is it possible to design an algorithm to reduce the complexity not to optimize it*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider iterating not from 1 to sqrt(n), but from sqrt(n) down to 1. First found divisor gives the answer and you don't need proceed further

Comment: Yes, this would be great. But, this is not the optimal one. i can give you a test case where your and mine approaches will take the same time to execute

Comment: Agreed. But unfortunately I can't imagine better approach finding divisors

Comment: Consider `3125` as a test case, you approach will take around 30 steps and mine will take roughly 25.